# What is the exact meaning of mean, and what is the easy way of getting it? I've heard two versions.

Tags: math-software, simple-functions

I am studying for Pre-GCSE maths paper and I need to learn Mode, Mean, Medium, Range and PTask. I have learnt all of them except the mode, infact I have learnt mode but I have heard two versions of it.

Say I had a mode array of: 1 5 6 7 0 0 3 4 0 5

Version 1:
1 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 31
31 divided by element count, so 31 divided by 10 = 3
I would write on my paper: 3

Version 2
1 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 31
31 divided by element count, so 31 divided by 10 = 3
Then some say I have to write it like below, I'm not sure how they get that number.
I would write on my paper: 3.1

Which version should I actually be writing on my paper? Will I get a mark for either? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I mean.. $31/10$ is $3.1$ and the average you are calculating is the mean.

Comment: $31/10\neq 3$.  What is correct to say is that $\lfloor 31/10\rfloor = 3$ where with the floor function we round down, but that is not the same thing as $31/10$.  The correct answer here is to take the exact value of the division without any rounding.  A more precise definition for a discrete setting with a finite number of data points is: Supposing our data set is $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$.  The mean of the data is $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$

Comment: "*I'm not sure how they get that number*"  $31/10 = 31\cdot \frac{1}{10}=31\cdot 0.1 = 3.1$.  However you wish to phrase the arithmetic, the end result is that $31/10=3.1\neq 3$